# Complex Analysis - Uniform Convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

> State The Weierstrass M-test, and use it to prove that if $\rho$ is a
>   positive real number then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac
>  n{e^{nz}}$$ is uniformely convergent on $\{x + iy \in \mathbb C : x
>  \ge \rho \} $

Could someone please help me find a bound for $\displaystyle \mid \frac{n}{e^{nz}} \mid$ to prove uniform convergence.

I got $\mid e^{nz} \mid=e^{xn}>e^{0}=1$ for $x>0$

And so, $\mid \frac{n}{e^{nz}} \mid<n$ However $n$ does not converge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $z=x+iy$ in $\mathbb C$ with $x\geqslant\rho$ and every $n$, $$\left|\frac{n}{\mathrm e^{nz}}\right|=n\mathrm e^{-nx}\leqslant n\mathrm e^{-n\rho},$$ hence $$\sum_n\left|\frac{n}{\mathrm e^{nz}}\right|\leqslant\sum_nn\mathrm e^{-n\rho}.$$ If $\rho\gt0$, then $\mathrm e^{-\rho}\lt1$ hence the series in the RHS converges and does not depend on $z$ such that $x\geqslant\rho$, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use monotonicity arguments to find the minimum of the function $t\mapsto t^{-3} e^{tx}$ for $t\geq 1$.

Comment: I am not sure what that is, could you please expand?

Comment: At any minimum, the derivative vanishes. Furthermore, the derivative is continuous, so away from an extremum, the function is monotone. These ideas suffice for you to make a rough sketch of the function after evaluating only in a few points!

Comment: How are we supposed to use the minimum of these functions?

Comment: @Did After minimal work, it implies that $n/e^{nx}\leq C/n^2$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: The question is whether anybody asking such a question would be able to complete said "minimal work".

Comment: Well, I would guess that anyone who knows that $\sum n x^n$ converges for $x<1$ would also be able to complete said argument. It remains only to observe that the exponential function in monotone.